# jquery UI draggable + sortable (cancel receive)

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

My scenario is I have a list of items that are draggable but not sortable and another list that is sortable. What I want to achieve is to drag from the draggable into the sortable but when I drop the item into the sortable I want to make an ajax request and depending on the answer to insert the item into the sortable or not. 
I tried to use on beforeStop or receive events for the sortable to cancel the item being added to the sortable but didn't find a solution.
I made a jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/5pTCd/21/

Answer (score -1):

Why not using your draggable/droppable in an accept/revert setting?

Here is a theoretical way to accomplish an **accept/revert drag & drop :**

First you need to set your draggable to revert if it is not accepted:

```
$(".drag").draggable({ revert: 'invalid' });
```

Then of course you could define what is valid in your droppable :

```
$(".drop").droppable({ accept: '.drag' });​
```

But thanks to the magic powder included in jQuery UI, you can insert a function as a value for "accept", it's returned value will define what you accept as a valid element:

```
$(".drop").droppable( { accept: function() {
    // return true or false
} });​
```

As an alternative you can use the dragstart event to change the accept option of your droppable :

```
$(".drag").draggable({
    start: function() { 
    // your ajax call and then a callback with :
    $(".drop").droppable("option","accept","#thisItemsID") }
});
```

Comment: What would you need to accept? If you sort, you are still in the same list. We can still have a sortable that is also droppable.